# How to capture Server Events in Elm

Tags: javascript, html, elm

I am trying to capture Server Events in Elm. But I couldn't found a library. Or I don't know default http library can do this.

Here is JavaScript code I wanted to write in Elm.

```
var source = new EventSource(
    '/event-stream?channel=channel&t=' + new Date().getTime());
```

There is obvious work around is I write JS code and port in Elm application. But I guess that will pollute the code. If I can have both in Elm, and possible I can join in Stream/Signal application would become fully reactive to Server. That is the end goal.

Please let me know if any further details are required.

PS: Above code is basic Html5 code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Elm 0.16, pushing values from the event stream in through a port is the best option for this. There's no way to access and instantiate an `EventSource` within Elm code.

Comment: isn't it possible to have something like http module?

Comment: You _can_ write a native wrapper in the style of elm-http or any of the core libraries that have native code, but doing so is very much discouraged and at your own risk. The way native wrappers work isn't documented or supported and may change drastically after any given Elm release. You'll have a hard time finding support on native wrapper code for these reasons as well. It's much safer to use a port.